# Next.js middleware and Link add query params to the url on links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, middleware

I am having the issue on the Link and middleware that catch params.

Project structure of my Next.js 12.2

1. pages/buy/[cid]
2. middleware.ts

Middleware.ts

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const isAllowedPageQuery = (queryParam: string, pathname: string): boolean => {
    const searchPageParams = ['order', 'price', 'keywords'];

    return (
        queryParam.includes('page') ||
      )
    );
};
// Define a middleware function that takes a NextRequest object as a parameter.
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { search, pathname, searchParams } = req.nextUrl;

    if (search) {
        const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
        const urlSearchParamsNew = new URLSearchParams('');
        const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
        const ToDelete: Array<string> = [];

        Object.entries(params).map(([key, value]) => {
            // check if the query parameter is allowed
            // if allowed, add it to the new URLSearchParams object
            // if not allowed, add it to the blacklist array
            isAllowedPageQuery(key, pathname)
                ? urlSearchParamsNew.set(key, value)
                : ToDelete.push(key);
        });
        const newUrl = req.nextUrl.origin + pathname + urlSearchParamsNew;

        if (ToDelete.length > 0) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(req.nextUrl, 301);
        }
    }
    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

When I click on a Link href="/buy/toy", the link will be xxxx.com/buy/toy?cid=toy

Is there a way the middleware can hide the params when I use a dynamic link with . Otherwise because the params is not in the isAllowedPageQuery the page goes into a infinite loop (using Next.js 12.2)...

because the params is not in the isAllowedPageQuery in the middleware to Next.Js the page goes into a infinite loop

Comment: You just need to check if the pathname is `/buy/[cid]` and the queryParam is `'cid'`